# Unable to access upsource from browser: ssl-no-cypher-overlap error

Tags: ssl, upsource

I have downloaded latest Hub (2018.4) and Upsource (2018.2) from jetbrains website.

I have successfully configured both a gentoo machine with https access and Upsource accessing the external Hub.

I have followed the same steps to replicate the installation on Ubuntu 16.04 (with all updates) and have both software start without issues. I am able to access Hub on the configure port (8443) but when i try to access Upsource i get a connection error from browsers (ffox 65, chrome 72, safari) stating SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

I have analyzed the connection with wireshark and both TLS Client Hello offer the cypher: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030) but in the case of Upsource there's no Server Hello but a simple Handshake Failure.

In both cases (gentoo and ubuntu) the certificates used are the same for Hub and Upsource and generated as per jetbrains [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/tls-keystores-and-certificates-for-server.html)

The only difference i can think of is the distribution but then, why i am able to access Hub but not Upsource?